# How to move old commits from a public branch to another branch?

Tags: git, version-control

The issue is we want to make a release from our **public** develop branch but before that we want to remove old commits from this branch belonging to a feature which is not yet ready to be released and move them to another branch.

I found solutions on StackOverflow that rebase the branch on itself and removes the commits, but i assume this would cause us a lot of merge issues because it would create whole new commits in place of all the other old ones and our develop branch is publicly active and being constantly updated by multiple people.

**How can we achieve this rewriting as least history and causing as least merge conflicts as possible?**

One idea I have thought of myself:

1. checkout a backup branch from develop
2. revert feature commits on develop
3. checkout a feature branch from develop
4. cherry-pick the reverted commits from backup branch to the feature branch. I assume this would create new commits and 'unrevert' the changes again.
5. when development on feature branch is finnally complete, rebase and merge back into develop branch

I haven't tested this yet, but do you think this would work?
Or can you suggest any better solutions?

Comment: You can try your idea on a fork to see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Seems like a legit approach to me. If you revert the commits individually, don't forget that you have to do that in reverse order (newest commit is reverted first, oldest commit is reverted last)